# jQuery function works intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm pretty stuck here.

I'm using a live search lookup script (AJAX) to lookup customers in the database using a input field. Upon selection I click my chosen customer. Then the form I am filling out for the customer is filled with those details from the database. The problem is only some of the time once clicked the fields are populated with data. It is completely intermittent, if I repetitively click the same customer eventually they will populate, it appears as though it works in bursts and fails it appears as though there is no pattern.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

```js
// ########## LIVE SEARCH FUNCTION ########## //
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
// ########## LIVE SEARCH FUNCTION ########## //

// ########## DATA POPULATE FUNCTION ########## // NOT WORKING ALL THE TIME
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

 jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
 
  $('#custid').val($clicked.find('.customerIdS').text());
  $('#firstName').val($clicked.find('.firstNameS').text());
  $('#lastName').val($clicked.find('.lastNameS').text());
  $('#companyName').val($clicked.find('.companyNameS').text());
  $('#streetAddressP').val($clicked.find('.streetAddressS').text());
  $('#suburbP').val($clicked.find('.suburbS').text());
  $('#stateP').val($clicked.find('.stateS').text());
  $('#postcodeP').val($clicked.find('.postcodeS').text());
  $('#phoneNumber').val($clicked.find('.phoneNumberS').text());
  $('#emailAddress').val($clicked.find('.emailAddressS').text());
 
 });
});
// ########## DATA POPULATE FUNCTION ########## // NOT WORKING ALL THE TIME
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" style="float:right;">

    <input id="searchid" class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for customer using first name, last name or company name."></input>

<br></br>

<div id="result" style="display: none;">

    <div class="show" align="left">
        <div class="selection">
            <span class="customerIdS">

                3628

            </span>
            <span class="firstNameS">

                David

            </span>
            <span class="lastNameS">

                Dodrel

            </span>

             - 
                                    

            <span class="companyNameS"></span>

            ,
                                    

            <span class="streetAddressS">

                101 Woodward Place

            </span>

            ,
                                    

            <span class="suburbS">

                Suburb

            </span>
            <span class="stateS">

                State

            </span>
            <span class="postcodeS">

                Postcode

            </span>
            <span class="phoneNumberS"></span>
            <span class="emailAddressS"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<div id="customerDetails" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
        <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber">
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of everything, consider stopp using "live" since it is deprecated. After that being said, i would say that you are attaching the event again each time your ajax returns something.
You should assign your event only once (that means: not as an ajaxComplete callback.

Comment: Thanks mindastic, I have tried taking it out of ajaxComplete that unfortunately hasn't worked what would be a good replacement for live()? *Edit, on() works good :) Still not luck solving the intermittent problem though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the code below, instead yours. Also, please, check the comments explaining what i think was wrong with your code.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".search").on("keyup", function() {
        var searchId, dataString;
        searchId = jQuery(this).val();
        dataString = "search=" + searchId;
        if (searchId) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    jQuery("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click", function(e){
        //No need to use "live" here since this whole block of code will be executed once the DOM is ready
        var $clicked = jQuery(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    jQuery("#searchid").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
    //This is only attached once since your "#results" div is there from the beginning and you only change its content, you don't remove and attach it again.
    jQuery("#result").on("click", ".selection", function(e){
        //You were getting jQuery(e.target) but i assume it wasn't what you wanted since you were getting the element that was clicked inside "#result" and not "#result" itself (that is where you find your content and then assign values based on it)
        var $clicked = jQuery(this);
        jQuery('#custid').val($clicked.find('.customerIdS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#firstName').val($clicked.find('.firstNameS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#lastName').val($clicked.find('.lastNameS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#companyName').val($clicked.find('.companyNameS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#streetAddressP').val($clicked.find('.streetAddressS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#suburbP').val($clicked.find('.suburbS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#stateP').val($clicked.find('.stateS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#postcodeP').val($clicked.find('.postcodeS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#phoneNumber').val($clicked.find('.phoneNumberS').text().trim());
        jQuery('#emailAddress').val($clicked.find('.emailAddressS').text().trim());
    });    

});
```

Comment: Hi Mindastic, thank you for your response :) Testing your code it does appear to be very reliable and worked every time I tried. It pulls in every customer from the list however. For example if I type an unusual name there is one customer that customer will be populated, if I type a common name like smith there may be 10 customers which populated the 10 customers concatenated. E.g. the last_field shows smith, smith, smith, smith, smith.

Comment: I see. By inspecting your snippet, i see that the code is wrapped on a div with id "customerDetails" ... does that div contains all the records? Or you have any kind of identifier for each set of data? for example, that div contains the class "row" but it isn't too much descriptive. So, if you could add another class to the container in your backend, for example "user-info-container", you could attach the event to that class instead of #result. So it would be jQuery("#result .user-info-container").on("click" ...) .. and that will fix the problem you are having now. Does it make sense?

Comment: Hi Midastic, yes each row from the database is output into the container div class .show and .selection (surrounding each customer). Using jQuery to select #result .selection the code no longer works. Also if I just use .selection it shows customers but once clicked the fields don't populate.